# How to display mutually exclusive fields in API model in Swagger UI

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, jsonschema, swagger-2.0

Is there any annotation or way to display mutually exclusive field in API model (JSON) correctly in swagger ?
eg. If I have following API model and I want to show field A and B are mutually exclusive e.g. Java class say AtoZ has following structure

```
class AtoZ {
   String A;
   String B;
   @ApiModelProperty(value ="This is field C", required = true)
   String C;
}
```

Let say field C is required as annotated above but field A and B are mutually exclusive i.e. only one of field is required/can exist. If both A and B are annotated as Optional (i.e. required =false) that will not enforce mutually exclusive constraint.

Wondering if there is any appropriate annotation in swagger which allow documenting this kind of structure in Swagger UI ?

Comment: Is your question about the OpenAPI syntax (e.g. how to define that in YAML/JSON) or specifically about Java annotations?

Comment: @Helen in nutshell the question is "how to display Java object (API model) that has  mutually exclusive properties correctly using swagger annotation" e.g. wrt to above question , if property String A and String B are mutually exclusive in class AtoZ how to display it in Swagger UI . Is there any annotation ? I couldn't find any but wondering if there is any other way other than making it (required = false)

Comment: Look into *oneOf*: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md#discriminator-object I never use it but that might be what you are looking for